# Why does kde in distplot look like a sin wave?

Tags: histogram, seaborn, kernel-density

[image: Screenshot]

I created a histogram in seaborn using distplot. My data is type int64, but the kde in the histogram is wavy. How can I fix it?

Comment: The kde is meant for continuous distributions. You clearly have a discrete distribution with only 6 values.The kde draws a gauss curve around each value and sums those. You could game the kde somewhat via `sns.distplot(..., kde_kws={'bw':1.1})`  setting the bandwidth for the kde to 1.1 or some nearby value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw distribution plot for discrete variables in seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48990594/how-to-draw-distribution-plot-for-discrete-variables-in-seaborn)

Comment: Appreciate the response and suggested work-around. Thanks.